# Firestore structure model

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Coming from SQL background and watching tutorials, I am trying to do a model in Firestore to understand how things work. I basically wants model a situation where user has multiple lists and every list has his friends ( to display names of friends). Does the below make sense?

```
Users
    "john@xyz.com"
         -Name: John Smith

    "celina@xyz.com"
         - Name: Celina West

    "dan@xyz.com"
         - Name: Dan Nelson

Lists
     "john@xyz.com"
           List_Titles
                  "List 1"
                       - <AutoGenId>: Celina West
                       - <AutoGenId>: Dan Nelson
```

anything with "-" is a field, anything with bracket it Document and anything without prefixes is collection.

One issue I find here, is that lets say a user updates his/her name. Then I have to go not to only Users Collection but through every subcollection List to look for that person and update name. I thought about using email ID instead of name but then that goes against the "structure the nosql db as you view it" way. Plus then everytime  I have to hit the Users tables in a seperate call for every Id to query the name.

Is my assumption correct?
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest a change to this structure. It's often best practice to disassociate keys from the data it contains. If the email address is used as a key, references to that node refer to that email. However, if the user changes their email, that means all of the references would need to be changed as well. But, keys cannot be changed, the nodes would need to be read and re-written. It would be much simpler to add a email child node and create the node key with push() or childByAutoId (swift) so it's 'generic'. That way, the email can be changed without having to re-create a bunch of nodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Snake, there is no perfect database structure. You need to model your database so you can query very easily later, when you need to do CRUD operations. In one of my [tutorials](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee), I have explained step by step how can we [structure](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=idywm80Qbvc&index=3&list=PLn2n4GESV0AmXOWOam729bC47v0d0Ohee&t=0s) a Firestore database which holds `users`, `lists` and `products`.

Please see the below database structure that can help achieve what you want.

```
{
  "users": {
    "appfirstuser@gmail.com": {
      "tokenId": "eGVzwv7Y...",
      "userEmail": "appfirstuser@gmail.com",
      "userName": "First User"
    },
    "appseconduser@gmail,com": {
      "tokenId": "cc8Uhriu...",
      "userEmail": "appseconduser@gmail.com",
      "userName": "Second User"
    }
  },
  "shoppingLists": {
    "appfirstuser@gmail.com": {
      "userShoppingLists": {
       "3Oe37QdcHXSohL2dnNlX": {
        "createdBy": "First User",
        "date": "February 3, 2018 at 2:56:31 PM UTC+2",
        "shoppingListId": "3Oe37QdcHXSohL2dnNlX",
        "shoppingListName": "Pharmacy"
    },
    "  WovuleVbTZdql68gXk84": {
        "createdBy": "First User",
        "date": "February 3, 2018 at 2:56:20 PM UTC+2",
        "shoppingListId": "WovuleVbTZdql68gXk84",
        "shoppingListName": "Grocery"
       }
      }
    }
  },
  "products": {
    "WovuleVbTZdql68gXk84": {
      "shoppingListProducts": {
       "8vinaHJyjG4JqFH33YE7": {
        "productId": "8vinaHJyjG4JqFH33YE7",
        "productName": "Milk"
    },
      "JALygtedMHWQcdEoSnPM": {
       "productId": "JALygtedMHWQcdEoSnPM",
       "productName": "Eggs"
    },
      "WFkJMWZSnhJU9iwGeoOi": {
        "productId": "WFkJMWZSnhJU9iwGeoOi",
        "productName": "Bacon"
       }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using a database structure that looks like this, you'll be abte to create, read, update and delete records very easily.

Comment: Hello Alex. Thank you I will check your Videos. With regard to the solution above, let me ask you a question. Let's say the user logs in with email and pass word and on the next screen you would display his lists names as well as the user name at the top. How would you change the model to accommodate that? Or will you do  2 queries (one for name and one for the list names)?

Comment: I'll keep the same structure but instead of getting the userName from the `GoogleSignInAccount` object, I'll get it from the `FirebaseUser` object.. Regarding the lists, will remain the same.

Comment: So in that case, you will do 2 queries. One is for the name of the user from the firebase user and one from the lists names from the lists object correct? Basically you don't recommend adding the name of the user under the list name so it is all grabbed in one query (firestore videos recommend structuring the dB the way you query it which u find it messy)

Comment: In the database structure above, there is a field named `createdBy` which is actually the `userName`. So you can query only once, to get the name of the list as well as the name of the user. And yes, that's correct, structuring the dB the way we query it. There is no single database strucutre. That's was my way if you have other structure that feets better for your use-case, feel freee to use it. Cheers!

Comment: aha I see. Sorry I missed the createdby. So in this case, if the user changes the name, then you have to navigate all the database to change the createdby field. I guess I am having hard time accepting given I come from SQL background, but it seems that's just the way noSql is

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Yes I was planning to as soon as we ended up the convo (which we did now :) ). Upvoted and accepted!